# Apache2 Startup warning: NameVirtualHost *:80 and NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I have a super simple Apache setup on a SUSE box that is giving me the error in the title.  Any ideas what it could be?  I have checked all the conf files and found no duplicate NameVirtualHost directives anywhere...

My listen.conf file looks like this (some goodies ommitted):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

and my vhost.conf file looks like this (some goodies ommitted):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName subdomain.somedomain.com
        ## OTHER STUFF ##
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName anothersubdomain.somedomain.com
        ## OTHER STUFF ##
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName someotherserver.somedomain.com
        ## OTHER STUFF ##
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This is totaly imcomplete for us to help you. Have you some <VirtualHost> directive ? Please paste a more complete example of your configuration. You really probably don't need NameVirtualHost if you use * as address

Comment: The formatting got a bit messed up.  Reformatted virtual host directives.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to enclose your ServerName somedomain.com ## OTHER STUFF ## inside

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
</VirtualHost>
```

tags. The error is saying that you have no virtual hosts defined for port 80 and 443. Change the *:80 to *:443 for an ssl host.

Answer (score 1):

Does your vhost.conf file look like that, or like *this*:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@address.com

    ServerName subdomain.somedomain.com

    # blah blah
</VirtualHost>
```

You need those VirtualHost tags set to the correct port.

Failing that, are you sure httpd.conf is calling vhosts.conf ?